# Running rsync with rsh option via exec.Command

Tags: go, ssh, rsync, rsh

I'm invoking [rsh](/questions/tagged/rsh) in [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) `exec.Command`:

```
rsh := fmt.Sprintf("--rsh=\"/usr/bin/ssh -p %s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l %s\"", *destPort, *destUserName)
cmd := exec.Command("rsync", "-avz", rsh, from, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", *destHost, to))
fmt.Println(cmd)
var outb, errb bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &outb
cmd.Stderr = &errb

err = cmd.Run()
fmt.Println(outb.String())
fmt.Println(errb.String())
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec /usr/bin/ssh -p 1999 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Tried to explicitly set the full path of `ssh` in `rsh`.

The output of `fmt.Println(cmd)` seems correct:

```
&{/usr/bin/rsync [rsync -avz --rsh="/usr/bin/ssh -p 1999 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root" /var/www/html/atlaserpsolution.com/production/altractors h3.ftp.datagix.com:/var/www/vhosts/atlas.ns513.datagix.com/atlaserp/documents/altractors] []  <nil> <nil> <nil> [] <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> false [] [] [] [] <nil> <nil>}
```

What's  wrong with my `exec.Command`?

Comment: You should not need to do any shell escaping here, please try specifiying the rsh command without quotes, like so:  `fmt.Sprintf("--rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -p %s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l %s")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are merging two arguments into one (`--rsh` and `/usr/bin/ssh ...`). Split them and it should work:

```
rsh := fmt.Sprintf("/usr/bin/ssh -p %s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l %s", *destPort, *destUserName)
cmd := exec.Command("rsync", "-avz", "--rsh", rsh, from, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", *destHost, to))
```

Comment: On second thought, the problem is probably the quotes more than combining the arguments. However, two arguments should be much clearer anyway.